# Nest two animations in android

Tags: java, android, animation

I'd like to implement an alpha animation when clicking one of the buttons.

The animation is: Alpha down from 1 to 0.5 and when it reaches the 0.5 back again from 0.5 to 1.
Cycling both animations. How can I do it? Is posible to define it in a xml file in `/res/anim` folder or is necesary to use the `AnimationListener`?

Thanks

Comment: Its for an request through Internet so I'd like the button keep flashing until the server respond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `AlphaAnimation` object to do this. Set the repeat mode to `setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE)` for changing alpha from 0.5 back to 1.0 and `setRepeatCount(count)` for number of times to repeat.

sample animation xml:

```
<alpha
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.5"
android:duration="1000" />
```

code for loading the xml:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
a.reset();
a.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
a.setRepeatCount(5); // will be infinite if -1
Button btn = (Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.clearAnimation();
btn.startAnimation(a);
```

Code is just a sample. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this using `AnimationListeners`. Inflate the animations and then call them in each other's `AnimationListener` `onAnimationEnd()` method. Can't say if this is the only way to achieve the effect, but nevertheless this works.